# Should I group by and then join, or join and then group by?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, partitioning, group-by

(oracle's optimizer does the same thing for both approaches when just two tables are involved, thus my question involves three tables)

Assume three tables `t1`, `t2` and `t3` with a pairwise `1:n` relationship from left to right:

```
t1 (1)--(n) t2 (1)--(n) t3
```

each partitioned on a common column `p` used in all joins and each with a primary key `id`, with foreign keys `t2.id1 -> t1.id` and `t3.id2 -> t2.id`.

In reality, the `n` (both of them) are small. Possibly about 2 `t2` rows for each `t1` row and about 3 `t3` rows for each one from `t2`.

I wish to join these tables like this:

```
select t1.id t1id, t2.id t2id, count(1) t3count
from t1 join t2 on (t1.p = t2.p and t1.id = t2.id1)
        join t3 on (t2.p = t3.p and t2.id = t3.id2)
group by t1.id, t2.id
```

It gives the count of `t3` rows for each `t2` row and joins the `t1` data to that. You could imagine getting the following output:

```
t1id t2id t3count
---- ---- -------
   1    1      3
   1    2      1
   1    3      2
   2    4      5
   3    5      1
   3    6      1
```

Now compare this query to:

```
with t3g as ( -- as in 't3 grouped'
    select id2, count(1) t3count
    from t3
    group by id2
)
select t1.id t1id, t2id, t3count
from t1 join t2  on (t1.p = t2.p  and t1.id = t2.id1)
        join t3g on (t2.p = t3g.p and t2.id = id2)
```

(This latter could have been written with a nested `select` instead of `with`).

Here I basically pre-group the `t3` table, and then join it with the other two tables.

The first select gives me the following plan in oracle:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      | 69578 |  5367K|       |  2363   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ALL  |      | 69578 |  5367K|       |  2363   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY       |      | 69578 |  5367K|  6336K|  2363   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN          |      | 69578 |  5367K|       |  1083   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | t2   | 81635 |  1275K|       |   256   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|*  5 |     HASH JOIN         |      | 70033 |  4308K|       |   823   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| t1   | 81622 |  1753K|       |   616   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| t3   | 70033 |  2804K|       |   204   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The optimizer decides to join t1 and t3 first, otherwise, nothing unexpected.

The second query gives the following plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         | 69578 |    21M|       |  3125   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                   |         | 69578 |    21M|  8144K|  3125   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   PART JOIN FILTER CREATE    | :BF0000 | 70033 |  7317K|       |   950   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    VIEW                      |         | 70033 |  7317K|       |   950   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     HASH GROUP BY            |         | 70033 |  2804K|  4424K|   950   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   5 |      PARTITION RANGE ALL     |         | 70033 |  2804K|       |   204   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL      | t3      | 70033 |  2804K|       |   204   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|   7 |   PARTITION RANGE JOIN-FILTER|         | 81622 |    17M|       |   876   (1)| 00:00:01 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
|*  8 |    HASH JOIN                 |         | 81622 |    17M|       |   876   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL        | t2      | 81635 |  4623K|       |   256   (1)| 00:00:01 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
|  10 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL        | t1      | 81622 |    12M|       |   616   (1)| 00:00:01 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now here the optimizer first groups `t3` as instructed, then joins `t1` and `t2` and then utilizes partitioning to join the grouped `t3` with the joined `t1-t2`.

If I add a where clause limiting by `t1.id`, I get the following, rather similar plans:

First select:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |      |     1 |    79 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                         |      |     1 |    79 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |      |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                        |      |     1 |    79 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                       |      |     1 |    63 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| t1   |     1 |    22 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | t1pk |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   7 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR          |      |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  8 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| t3   |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  9 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                | t3fk |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 10 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | t2pk |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 11 |    TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID  | t2   |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Second select:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |      |     1 |   311 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                            |      |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                           |      |     1 |   311 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                          |      |     1 |   253 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID   | t1   |     1 |   164 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | t1pk |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   6 |     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                |      |     1 |    89 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   7 |      SORT GROUP BY                       |      |     1 |    41 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  8 |       FILTER                             |      |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   9 |        PARTITION RANGE SINGLE            |      |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 10 |         TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| t3   |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 11 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                | t3fk |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 12 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | t2pk |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 13 |   TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID     | t2   |     1 |    58 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

While I vaguely understand what the optimizer is doing, I can't conclude which query is better. Is there something glaringly obvious in the plans that should instruct me to prefer one query over the other, or do they seem rather equivalent performance-wise?

Note about limiting by `t1.id`: I have simplified the description of the tables and the relationships between them for the sake of simplicity. In this sense, it may seem that filtering by `t1.id` won't be performant for `t3` because it apparently doesn't have an index containing `t1.id`. In reality, `t2` is a *weak entity*, with primary key `(t1.id, t2.id)` and `t3`'s foreign key towards `t2` is exactly like that, including `t1.id`. That's why there is an index range scan on `t3fk` in the last two plans above.

Comment: From the plan on the second version (group on t3), looks like the optimizer thinks the grouping won't reduce the number of rows at all. Could you tell us what sort of stats you have on each of the t columns?

Comment: off topic: I think to say "three tables t1, t2, t3 with a pairwise 1:n relationship" does not make sense because this would mean `t1(1)--(n)t2, t1(1)--(n)t3, t1(2)--(n)t3, t2(1)--(n)t1, t3(1)--(n)t1, t3(1)--(n)t2`.

Comment: @Mat: could you help me with what to select from which view/table to answer your question?

Comment: @miracle173: fixed the semantics, thanks.

Comment: You can look at dba_tab_col_statistics (where owner = ? and table = ?), and also potentially dba_tab_histograms (filter on owner, table and column names) if the "histograms" value of the col_statistics view isn't "none".

Comment: Join t1 with t2 and t1 with t3 and not t2 with t3. Does that gives an improvent?

Answer (score 1):

The optimizer always tries to reduce the amount of data as quickly as possible. If not, your statistics might not be good.

Your plan 1 shows that less rows are processed this is good. The optimizer was able to reduce the amount of data more quickly. The numbers might not be exactly true but it gives you an idea based on the optimizer statistics.

Plan 1:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |      |     1 |    79 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                         |      |     1 |    79 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |      |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                        |      |     1 |    79 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                       |      |     1 |    63 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| t1   |     1 |    22 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | t1pk |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   7 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR          |      |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  8 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| t3   |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  9 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                | t3fk |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 10 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | t2pk |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 11 |    TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID  | t2   |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It shows that Oracle did a *HASH GROUP BY* while plan 2 did a *SORT GROUP BY*.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |      |     1 |   311 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                            |      |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                           |      |     1 |   311 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                          |      |     1 |   253 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID   | t1   |     1 |   164 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | t1pk |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   6 |     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                |      |     1 |    89 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   7 |      SORT GROUP BY                       |      |     1 |    41 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  8 |       FILTER                             |      |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   9 |        PARTITION RANGE SINGLE            |      |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 10 |         TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| t3   |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 11 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                | t3fk |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 12 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | t2pk |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 13 |   TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID     | t2   |     1 |    58 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Conclusion:** In most cases I would prefer a *HASH GROUP BY*. So in plan 1 Oracle does a better the GROUP BY much later with much less data. 2 reasons why plan 1 is better.

I assume that this is not the only SQL statement which will be using this join constellation. You will have to decide for each SQL which way is the best.

If you have a SQL similar to the following, the with clause can be much better:

```
with t3g as ( -- as in 't3 grouped'
    select id2, count(1) t3count
    from t3
    where id = :1 -- new line !!!!!!!!
    group by id2
)
select t1.id t1id, t2id, t3count
from t1 join t2  on (t1.p = t2.p  and t1.id = t2.id1)
        join t3g on (t2.p = t3g.p and t2.id = id2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the partitioning column in the initial query, it should be possible to complete the queries entirely from indexes.  This should be significantly faster.

Given this example I would drop t1 and t2 as the key columns should be available from t3.   This should be significantly faster.

If you need data from t1 and/or t2, join them to t3.  Check the plan when you limit on t3.id rather than t1.id.

Plans without a limiting clause usually use full table scans which tend to be the fastest way to access all rows.  The plan can differ significantly from the plan with a limiting clause.

The optimizer tries to limit the cost of accessing the data.  These rules may be applied:

- Table scan if more than a few percent of the rows need to be accessed.
- Select the smallest result set first.
- If all columns are in an index, access data from an index rather than a table, .